# How to get Mono 3.5 on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04.4

Tags: ubuntu, mono

Not getting any luck installing Mono 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04.4. Pointers appreciated.

`apt-get install mono-reference-assemblies-3.5
mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.1 (Debian 4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4)`

Seems to default to Mono 4 regardless?

My actual requirement is to run "Project 5: Sightseer" headless dedicated. That dies with/after:

`mono --runtime=3.5 ./P5SServer.exe
WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
Using default runtime: v4.0.30319
Can't find custom attr constructor image: /home/steam/Steam/sightseer/P5SServer.exe mtoken: 0x0a000001
Unhandled loader error: 8, (null) System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 (null)
* Assertion: should not be reached at loader.c:298`

Somebody with Mono experience point me in the right direction?

Comment: Getting comments over at the Project 5: Sightseer's Discord that I need mono-complete. That however wants x11 + the kitchen sink. However, I'll give that a bash and see if it solves.

I'm making a large guess here, that the "Unhandled loader error:" line is maybe referring to the requirement for System.Core namespace etc?

Lol, takes me back to DOS days with vague unheard of error numbers. If it asks "(A)bort, (R)etry, (I)gnore" I'll get nostalgia :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in this case for the error message I had, was to install mono-complete. (apt-get install mono-complete)

I suspect the version 3.5 reference isn't the reason it would not run (this based on the developers comment that I needed 3.5 and the reason it wasn't working), it was actually various libraries or namespaces that were missing.